# Pip does not install dependencies declared in setup.py with install_requires

Tags: python, matplotlib, pip, pypi

In a Python project, I am using `install_requires` in my `setup.py` as follows.

```
install_requires=['numpy', 'scipy', 'matplotlib']
```

I then create the source, binary and wheels as follows.

```
python setup.py sdist bdist bdist_wheel
```

When I publish, I use `twine`.

```
twine upload --repository dist/testpypi mypackage-0.1.1-py2-none-any.whl
```

In a Python 2.7 conda environment, I then attempt to test the install.

```
pip install -i https://test.pypi.org/simple/ mypackage==0.1.1
```

However, I get the following error message:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement matplotlib (from mypackage) (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for matplotlib (from mypackage)
```

When I do a `pip list` and `conda list`, indeed, there is no `matplotlib` package listed.

What am I doing wrong? I thought (this point is where my understanding breaks down) that `install_requires` would list the prerequistes and `pip install` would pick up on that and automatically install the requirements? However, it seems that `install_requires` is acting as a guard against installing a package if its declared dependencies are not already installed.

In some internet searches, they seem to suggest that I include a `requirements.txt` via `MANIFEST.in` (e.g. `include requirements.txt`) and then `pip install` will auto-install the dependencies. However, after trying that approach, I still get the same error message. I tried with `requirements.txt` as follows.

```
matplotlib
```

And also as follows.

```
matplotlib>=2.2.3
```

How do I configure/setup `setup.py` and my distribution such that `pip install` or `conda install` will auto-install the declared dependencies via `install_requires`?

Comment: Would you mind let us try it? By giving the package's name?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that pip looks for packages in same repository as selected package. So if you provide to use `https://test.pypi.org/simple/` then it looks here for packages instead on `https://pypi.org/simple/`.

U think that you need to use `--extra-index-url` parameter

```
--extra-index-url <url>     Extra URLs of package indexes to use in addition to --index-url. Should follow the same rules as --index-url.
```

So try:

```
pip install -i https://test.pypi.org/simple/ --extra-index-url https://pypi.org/simple/ mypackage==0.1.1
```